# equivalent version of 'The daily grind'

Tags: words, colloquial-language, phrases, proverbs

I'm writing a composition about my daily routine & so clearly the content of the composition won't be particularly interesting. 
So I'd like to try and use a more creative title for the composition. 
**Is there a Japanese equivalent for the English saying 'the daily grind'?** 
If not, are there any alternative titles you think would be fitting? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There naturally is no "official" equivalent in Japanese (partly because many of us actually like to work in the first place.)  Phrases that might be close in meaning and nuance would include:

「退屈{たいくつ}な日課{にっか}」

「日々{ひび}の雑務{ざつむ}」

「毎日{まいにち}の骨折{ほねお}り仕事{しごと}」

Answer (score 0):

[毎日の仕事](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=daily%20grind) is what comes up in the dictionary, I don't think there is a specific term for itself in Japanese.

Similar term could be 毎日の繰り返し - "the repetitive everyday".

Comment: 「毎日の仕事」 sounds completely neutral and it carries absolutely no negative connotation.